# How do I enable choosing all of my installed desktop environments on Fedora 23?

Tags: fedora, desktop-environment

I installed Fedora 23 with GNOME. Then, I used the command `sudo dnf install @mate-desktop @kde-desktop @xfce-desktop @lxde-desktop @cinnamon-desktop`to install MATE, KDE, XFCE, LXDE, and Cinnamon. However, on the login screen, I can only choose from a few options - GNOME, GNOME Classic, GNOME on Wayland, and Plasma. Why can't I choose MATE, XFCE, LXDE, or Cinnamon? How do I enable these choices?

Answer (score 4):

Doing those installs *part* of the desktop, but does not install the packages to make them complete.  If you install

```
mate-desktop
cinnamon-desktop
plasma-desktop
xfce4-session
lxde-common
```

that seems to get what is needed.  You can see the gdm data in `/usr/share/xsessions` as a set of ".desktop" files:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root          711 Jul 11 11:30   LXDE.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root         7494 Nov 12 07:34   gnome-classic.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root         7551 Nov  6 10:34   gnome.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root         6915 Nov  9 17:54   mate.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root          198 Jul  2 05:03   openbox.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root         2051 Nov 16 05:17   plasma.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root         5465 Sep 12 17:54   xfce.desktop
```

and the actual packages owning these files

```
$ rpm -qf *
lxde-common-0.99.0-1.fc23.noarch
gnome-classic-session-3.18.2-1.fc23.noarch
gnome-session-xsession-3.18.1.2-2.fc23.x86_64
mate-session-manager-1.12.0-1.fc23.x86_64
openbox-3.6.1-1.fc23.x86_64
plasma-workspace-5.4.3-3.fc23.x86_64
xfce4-session-4.12.1-6.fc23.x86_64
```

This thread provided the necessary clue: *[How to start KDE from GDM ?](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-start-kde-from-gdm-218335/)*

Per comment, the *recommended* way to install a desktop is via the `groupinstall` feature.  You would get the list of groups to install using one of these:

```
dnf group list
dnf grouplist
```

(which give the same result).  That shows several possibilities under "Available environment groups".  For each, you could do something like

```
dnf groupinstall 'MATE Desktop'
```

but in a quick check, the dependencies were already satisfied by my earlier install.  I recall from `yum` (and think it possible for `dnf`)
that (like "groupinstall" versus "group install") that there's some flexibility in the parameters.  The `dnf` manual page refers to the "@" syntax used by OP as an *environment*, and ignoring case and the "-" versus space in the names, OP's selection of names matches the list which I see from `dnf grouplist`.  Based on that, it seems that OP was following the recommended procedure, but that it did not work.

Comment: Would I install the packages that you named in addition to or in place of the ones the I installed?

Comment: I installed the first list, and then (curious to validate the ".desktop" files) listed the packages where *those* occurred.  You probably want the first list, to get functional desktop environments.  (I hadn't gotten around to installing Fedora23, so did this investigation to satisfy my curiousity).

Comment: +1 to this, but note that the way to install the desktop environments is via comps groups, not by the individual packages. Try `dnf grouplist` and `dnf groupinstall`.

Comment: I'm aware of the group feature, but with your reminder, and looking at the manual page it seems that the "@" syntax attempted by OP was the group feature - and that did not work as intended.  My answer was however directed towards solving OP's immediate problem.